# Proper method for combining Attention, Multi, Residual cell wrappers in 1.1.0-rc2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am attempting to combine the following:

```
tf.contrib.rnn.AttentionCellWrapper
tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell
tf.contrib.rnn.ResidualWrapper
tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell
```

I am constructing the cell in the following manner

```
  cell = tf.contrib.rnn.AttentionCellWrapper(
    tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([
    tf.contrib.rnn.ResidualWrapper(
      cell=tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(dec_units))
      for _ in range(dec_layers)]),
      attn_length=attn_len)
```

This works fine if I keep the attn_len small (1-2) but increasing the attn_len to a larger value (5+) causes the script to hang indefinitely with one CPU core pegged at 100% at the start of training (0 steps are completed).

Is this the appropriate way to combine these elements?  Should I be overriding the defaults on the optional parameters?